# QGIS - Linking origin and destination points with nearby routes (vectors)

Tags: qgis, merge

**Context**

- Dataset A contains the origin and destination coordinates of trips made by car in CSV format (n=~1M).
- Dataset B contains public transport routes for the same area in vector format (GPKG with ~600 features).

**Objectives**
I want to estimates how many of the trips in Dataset A could have been made using public transport. I consider that a trip could easily have been made using public transport if it originates and ends within 400 meters of a public transport route.

**Initial Approach**
My initial thinking was to import Dataset A in QGIS, use the "Join attributes by nearest" tool, and export the joined layer back to CSV for further processing in Stata.

**Problems faced**

1. My first problem is that Dataset A is too big, which makes QGIS slow down or crash.
2. I tried splitting Dataset A in 100 parts, but I haven't found a way to batch import and project them (which is needed to calculate a 400-meter buffer).

Edit: problems 1 and 2 are solved using the following code to import CSV files in bulk

```
import os.path, glob
layers=[] # makes an empty list

# Define path to  directory of your csv files
path_to_csv = "*path to where the files are*"

# Set current directory to path of csv files
os.chdir(path_to_csv)

for fname in glob.glob("*.csv"): # Change this base path


    uri = "file:///" + path_to_csv + fname + "?encoding=%s&delimiter=%s&xField=%s&yField=%s&crs=%s" % ("UTF-8",";", "lon", "lat","epsg:4326")

#Make a vector layer
    eq_layer=QgsVectorLayer(uri, fname, "delimitedtext")

#Check if layer is valid
    if not eq_layer.isValid():
        print ("Layer not loaded")

#Add CSV data    
    QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(eq_layer)
```

3. After the join, the Joined layer is even bigger, since each observation in Dataset is joined to an average of 150 features from Dataset B (I never quite get there because the program crashes or freezes before).
4. The "Join attributes by nearest" tool creates one record/line per match. Instead, it would be more manageable for me if the output dataset stored each in matched public transport route as a distinct column/variable (the number of lines in the dataset would remain unchanged, only the number of columns would increase).

**Questions**

1. Does my approach make sense? Is there a much more efficient way to do this that I haven't considered?
2. Any ideas on how to solve the problems listed above?

I am not familiar with Python, but willing to learn the basics if that's the solution. For now, I work mostly with Stata and know how to use QGIS.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour], which emphasizes the importance of asking One question per Question. Any Question with a bullet list of questions is likely to be closed, as are Questions that ask for opinions or ideas. In theory, [Chat] would be a place to have discussions, but Chat doesn't get the traffic necessary for it to be useful (and it has a minimum reputation requirement anyway).

Comment: For larger dataset, you may want to have a look at a spatial database (like Postgres+PostGIS). For example, you would load the points + routes, add spatial indexes, then select the routes of interest with two `where exists()` clauses applied on the starting/ending points.

Comment: Thank you JHG and Vince and sorry for making the question too wide.

I have decided to follow my original approach I am happy to share that I have solved problem #2 (no able to import CSV files in batch).